# Collapse rows across group and remove duplicates and NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, nest, summarize

I would like to collapse values across rows within a group and remove duplicates and NAs. I have tried several `{tidyverse}` approaches, including `purrr::nest`, `dplyr::summarize(x = paste(x, collapse = ", ") and` dplyr::summarize(x = list(x)`, and haven't gotten it to work. I would be grateful for your help! A reprex of the input and desired output is below.

```r
# Collapse rows across group and remove duplicates and NAs

library(dplyr)

df_in <- tribble(
  ~group, ~subgroup, ~color, ~shape, ~emotion, ~shade,
  1,      "a",       "red",   NA,   "happy",   NA,
  1,      "a",       "red",   NA,   "sad",   "striped"
)

df_in
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   group subgroup color shape emotion shade  
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <lgl> <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1     1 a        red   NA    happy   <NA>   
#> 2     1 a        red   NA    sad     striped


df_out <- tribble(
  ~group, ~subgroup, ~color, ~shape, ~emotion,    ~shade,
  1,      "a",       "red",   NA,   "happy, sad", "striped"
)

df_out
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   group subgroup color shape emotion    shade  
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <lgl> <chr>      <chr>  
#> 1     1 a        red   NA    happy, sad striped
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `group_by` with `summarise(across(everything(), ...))` to apply a function to every column. That function in our case is written as a formula (the `~`-notation), in which the column is called `.x`.

As you suggested, we can `paste` (with `collapse = ", "`) the rows together. I remove the `NA` values with `.x[!is.na(.x)]`.

```
df_in %>% 
  group_by(group, subgroup) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ paste(unique(.x[!is.na(.x)]), collapse = ", "))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

The only difference with your expected output is that the `shape` column is now an empty string instead of an `NA` value:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 6
  group subgroup color shape emotion    shade  
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>  
1     1 a        red   ""    happy, sad striped
```

That can be fixed by for example creating a function that replaces the zero-length list with `NA` before pasting.

```
paste_rows <- function(x) {
  unique_x <- unique(x[!is.na(x)])
  if (length(unique_x) == 0) {
    unique_x <- NA
  }
  
  paste(unique_x, collapse = ", ")
}

df_in %>% 
  group_by(group, subgroup) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), paste_rows)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```